# MySQL Workbench crashing due to long string with raw hex(?) values

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I copy and pasted a value out of a SQL table and into the editor window, I didn't realize this string had some strange values in it, it looks like this: [image]

I can't get rid of it now without crashing MySQL Workbench. Every time I try to edit it or delete the string I get the MacOS spinner and finally the system runs out of application memory and I have to force quit the application.

I tried deleting the cache file associated with this DB connection but it did not fix the problem. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get rid of that editor content simply remove the saved workspace. Open the log folder, via the Help menu, and go up one level. You will find a `workspace` folder which contains subfolders, one for each connection. Remove the one that causes trouble (keep Workbench closed while doing that).